# $\lim_{x\to 0}\left[1^{\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}}+2^{\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}}+3^{\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}}+\cdots + n^{\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}}\right]^{\sin^2x}$

Tags: limits

> $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left[1^{\frac{1}{\sin^2x}}+2^{\frac{1}{\sin^2x}}+3^{\frac{1}{\sin^2x}}+\cdots + n^{\frac{1}{\sin^2x}}\right]^{\sin^2x}$$

Limit is  of form $(\infty)^{0} $
$$\lim_{x\to 0}e^{\sin^2x\log{ {\left[1^{\frac{1}{\sin^2x}}+2^{\frac{1}{\sin^2x}}+3^{\frac{1}{\sin^2x}}+\cdots + n^{\frac{1}{\sin^2x}}\right]}}}$$

I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Easier to see that if $x\to 0$ then $y=1/\sin^2 x\to +\infty$, and try to compute: $$\lim_{y\to +\infty} \left[1^y+2^y+\cdots+n^y\right]^{1/y}$$ The $\sin^2 x$ part is essentially an irrelevant complication.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yeah! Question was really easy .Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$n^y\leq 1^y+2^y+3^y+\cdots + n^y\leq n^y+n^y+\cdots+n^y=n^{y+1}$$

Comment: I think taking $n^y $ common from all term will be enough.

Comment: I don't understand why you have written this inequality.

Comment: I find using the squeeze lemma simpler here, but to each their own. @AakashKumar

Comment: If $f(x)\leq g(x)\leq h(x)$ and $f(x)\to L$ and $h(x)\to L$ then by the squeeze lemma, $g(x)\to L$. So raise each term here to $1/y$ then note that $(n^y)^{1/y}=n\to n$ and $(n^{y+1})^{1/y}=n^{1+1/y}\to n$. @AakashKumar

Comment: This is a very nice way forward!  Good to see you're back Thomas.  -Mark

Comment: Never left, @Dr.MV

Answer (score 4):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^{\csc^2(x)}\right)^{\sin^2(x)}&=n\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n (k/n)^{\csc^2(x)}\right)^{\sin^2(x)} \tag 1\\\\
&=n \tag 2
\end{align}$$

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$ we proceeded by evaluating the limit

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n (k/n)^{\csc^2(x)}\right)^{\sin^2(x)} &=\lim_{x\to 0}e^{\sin^2(x)\log\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(k/n)^{\csc^2(x)}\right)}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}e^{\sin^2(x)\,O\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(k/n)^{\csc^2(x)}\right)}\\\\
&=e^0\\\\
&=1 \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to0}\left[1^{\frac1{\sin^2(x)}}+2^{\frac1{\sin^2(x)}}+3^{\frac1{\sin^2 (x)}}+\cdots+n^{\frac1{\sin^2(x)}}\right]^{\sin^2(x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[1^x+2^x+3^x+\cdots+n^x\right]^{1/x}\\
&=n\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\left(\frac1n\right)^x+\left(\frac2n\right)^x+\left(\frac3n\right)^x+\cdots+\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^x+1^x\right]^{1/x}\\[4pt]
&=n\,[0+0+0+\cdots+0+1]^0\\[8pt]
&=n
\end{align}
$$

Comment: A bit like mine.  ;-))

Answer (score 1):

This is not in the form of$(\infty)^0$ as $1^{\infty}$ is undetermined, so try this process.[image]

Comment: robjohn sir, you have done similar to my process